# AES 256 encryption Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, hash, aes

I have a source code for data encryption aes256 based, but this code is Java and I want transform to PHP, I was trying with this example, but isn't correct. The examples in PHP use random IV but I require them to be zeros.

```java
private String encryptAES(String strToEncrypt) {
    
    try {
        byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.toCharArray(), SALT.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

I tried this

```php
function encrypt($data){
    $method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $salt = 'vzQ8p=z';
    $key =  '!5&3usT';

    $iv = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
    $chars = array_map("chr", $iv);
    $IVbytes = join($chars);

    $hash = openssl_pbkdf2($key,$salt,'256','65536', 'sha1');
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $IVbytes);
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason, your IV should not be zero.  You should not even encrypt to things with the same IV, much less everything with zero.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious flaw is that while both use PBKDF2, you're using HMAC-SHA2-256 as the PRF (pseudo-random function, i.e. hash algorithm) in the Java code, and SHA1 as the PRF in the PHP. That will of course produce two different keys (just as if you ran the same string through SHA1 and SHA2-256), so your text will get encrypted to two different ciphertexts and need the corresponding key in each case to decrypt it.

You also need to check that you're using the same cipher and padding scheme in both cases. You explicitly specify AES-256-CBC in PHP, but not the padding; you explicitly specify AES/CBC/PKCS5 in Java, but not the AES key size. In practice I suspect that it's correct here (Java probably generates a 256-bit AES key when passed a 256-bit KeySpec, and PHP `openssl_encrypt` with `AES-256-CBC` probably uses PKCS5 by default), but you shouldn't leave anything unspecified.

Other thoughts:

- Why use PBE/PBKDF2? Unless the `SECRET_KEY`/`$key` is a user-memorized value, there's no reason to do this every time; it's a waste of CPU time.
- If the "key" is actually hardcoded (as it is in the example), that's even worse. Not only is it totally pointless to run PBKDF2 on a hardcoded "key" (password) and salt, it's a terrible idea to use a hardcoded key (or hardcoded derivation process for a key) because everything will get encrypted with that same key on every system, and anybody who sees your code or decompiles the app will know what key every bit of data this system ever touched was encrypted with.
- As [@foreverska's comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/261322/aes-256-encryption-java-to-php#comment540561_261322) points out, you should never reuse an IV, and should definitely never hardcode one. Using a zero IV is not *quite* as bad as outright using ECB instead of CBC, but it's still very bad indeed. If you actually need to use an always-zero IV, somebody has screwed up very badly.
- There's no integrity protection on this encryption. Bit-flipping attacks in CBC aren't quite as bad as in steam ciphers or stream-like modes of operation, but they're still a real threat. You need to protect the message integrity, ideally by using authenticated encryption (and verifying the authentication tag when decrypting).
- Without looking at the decryption code we can't say for sure if this is a problem, but PKCS5 is potentially vulnerable to padding oracle attacks. Depending on how exactly the decryption process handles incorrect padding, an attacker who can try to decrypt the same message (plus attacker-chosen modification) many times may be able to decrypt the message without knowing the key themselves (though that's generally a moot point if you hardcode the key).